# Are there still "unsolvable" positions for computers, post Alpha Zero?

Tags: computer-chess

Yeah, yeah, duplicate...
[Dupe A](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/are-there-positions-which-cannot-be-properly-analyzed-by-any-computer)
[Dupe B](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23837/solvable-studies-that-computers-fail-to-crack)
...but the times they are a-changing. For example, I tried [this "rambling rook" piece](https://www.yacpdb.org/#search/ODg4ODg4ODgvSGVubmViZXJnZXIsIE1vcml6Ly8vLy8vLy8vLy8vLzEvMS8xLzA=/1) by Henneberger, Lichess Stockfish found a #31 on depth 93 or so. The famous Nxb6 trap (can't find it offhand) has long been avoided with deep enough depth (White instead gangs upon Pa5 and wins slowly). The ["Penrose"](https://www.chess.com/news/view/will-this-position-help-to-understand-human-consciousness-4298) now also gets an immediate yawning "0.0" by Stockfish.

The question probably breaks down to which depth the super modern engines can reach, and if a problem can have its punchline beyond this horizon. (E.g., any "Penrose" style fortress problem will only need a depth of 100 halfmoves, when the 50 move rule kicks in, so this won't impress a modern engine.)

Comment: Yes. The starting position...

Comment: If you already know its a "Duplicate" with Dupe A Dupe B , why post? 

Short Answer is No... Alpha Zero works differently to other engines, so after an initial "viewing" of n amount of games. It will use its AI just to kick something off.

Comment: @DavidBateman how does AlphaZero working differently detract from this question? AlphaZero style engines aren't even good at all tactics, for instance in a correspondence game I had a position where Stockfish would find a tactical solution but Leela would not. (but since Stockfish did find it, that doesn't really help here)

Comment: In case you are interested though, I have not tried recently so maybe Leela can find it now, but not the last time I tried. White to play and win: r5r1/1np3bk/1p1p4/3P4/bpP2PPp/P3N2P/1q1BQ2K/4R1R1 w - - 0 33

Comment: @SmallChess unsolvable for computers but solvable for humans?

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/positions-that-stump-engines This is also closely related.